# File Sharing reverts to old settings

Tags: big-sur, sharing, system-settings, file-sharing

Having issues with our file sharing settings on our file server (Mac mini running macOS 11.6 / Big Sur).

The first issue is that following a restart File Sharing is disabled. If we lose power or have to restart the Mac then we have to remember to open System Preferences > Sharing and enable file sharing. More of an annoyance than anything.

The other issue is a bit more irritating, we have removed a user from the users pane of a shared folder several times now and they keep re-appearing once we close and re-open System Preferences. This behavior *feels* like a corrupt preference file but I haven't been able to track down which plist is responsible for the file sharing settings.

So far we've blown away the File Sharing settings (remove all shared folders from the preference pane) and re-installed macOS without doing a full erase, however the issues have persisted.

The Mac in question is the file and directory server for a lab of 45 Macs. Sharing is to roughly 225 students.

Any ideas what to do next? (aside from erase and re-install the OS)